# sencha touch :: how to make a popup panel flip

Tags: popup, sencha-touch, panel, flip

I have a popup panel opened in sencha touch and I want to make it flip around to show another popup panel.how could I realise that? thnx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I am sorry it is not tested)

You want to do something like this on some event or action in your code:

```
panel_to_hide.hide({type: 'flip',duration: 5000});
```

and then

```
panel_to_show.show({type: 'flip',duration: 5000}); //may be you want to place this in hide event of the first panel.
```

Please let me know if it works.